# Finding Stream codes for State of Utah?

Tags: data, arcgis-online, united-states

Does anyone know where I can find Stream (rivers, waterbodies) codes for the State of Utah?

Comment: I think we need more info...are you talking NHD stream codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The high resolution [Flowline layer in the NHD's mapservice](http://services.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/nhd/MapServer/39) has a ReachCode attribute, which is defined [here](http://nhd.usgs.gov/NHDDataDictionary_model2.0.pdf) as:

> Unique identifier for a ‘reach’. The first eight numbers are the
>   WBD_HUC8. The next six numbers are randomly assigned, sequential
>   numbers that are unique within a HUC8, 14-char value

In theory you should be able to do this all via http using published map services.  However, I get a 404 when I copy and paste the geometry returned by this query for Utah ..

http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/5/query?text=Utah&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&objectIds=&where=&time=&returnCountOnly=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&outSR=&outFields=&f=pjson

... into the [filter geometry textbox of the NHD's mapservice](http://services.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/nhd/MapServer/39/query) and click Query (POST).  It even happens when `Return Count only` set to true, and everything else false.

Answer (score 4):

You could also download the NHD data for your state, open the Feature Classes of the FGD in ArcMap/ArcCatalog, and open the attribute table and look them up by whatever attribute you are using, i.e. Feature Name, Reach Code, etc. [NHD High Resolution by State FTP](ftp://nhdftp.usgs.gov/DataSets/Staged/States/FileGDB/HighResolution/)

Comment: I appreciate all your input, I was unsuccesful with using all your suggestions. None of us in the office were able to find the codes. :(